# Need help to join 2 select queries from 1 table with 2 different conditions

Tags: sql, join, select, conditional-statements

I'm getting problems with some simples SELECT queries :

```
SELECT QuestResource.limit_level, StringResource_FR.value FROM QuestResource, StringResource_FR WHERE StringResource_FR.code=QuestResource.text_id_quest ORDER BY limit_level, id

SELECT StringResource_FR.value FROM NPCResource, StringResource_FR WHERE StringResource_FR.code=NPCResource.text_id

SELECT StringResource_FR.value FROM NPCResource, StringResource_FR WHERE StringResource_FR.code=NPCResource.name_text_id
```

The problem is that I need the strings (StringResource.value) linked to some ID's (QuestResource.text_id_quest, NPCResource.text_id, NPCResource.name_text_id) and I can't get the queries to work in one simple query and in one table.

So I think this is a trivial query and sql.sh didn't helped me so I'm asking here =)

Thx for the help.

Need some help for basic query and need advices to learn efficiently SQL language

Answer (score 0):

First, ditch whatever learning resource you're using that suggested you should join tables using `,`.  The `JOIN` syntax is soon approaching its 30th birthday...  *(ANSI-92)*

*(Search online for `SQL JOIN TUTORIAL` and there are many good resources to use.)*

Then, use aliases to join the same table multiple times...

```
SELECT
  NPCResource.*,
  StringText.value   AS text_string,
  StringName.value   AS name_string
FROM
  NPCResource
INNER JOIN
  StringResource_FR     StringText
    ON StringText.code = NPCResource.text_id
INNER JOIN
  StringResource_FR     StringName
    ON StringName.code = NPCResource.name_text_id
```

Comment: Thx, i've already seen this technic before but it was the " StringResource_FR     StringText" that i didn't understood. For me it looks like an AS but I'm not sure if that's it.

Comment: @spekuloos It is, but Oracle doesn't accept using AS there, and you didn't say which dialect you're using, so I played safe.

Comment: Thx for your help, I will use the JOIN Syntax now !